# Difficulty Proving First-Order Convexity Condition

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I'm independently working through Boyd and Vandenberghe's "Convex Optimization" and am stuck on the following step in their proof of the first-order convexity condition on page $70$.

> If we divide both sides by $t$, we obtain
>   $$f(y) \geq f(x) + \frac{f(x + t(y-x))-f(x)}{t}$$
>   and taking the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$, yields 
>   $$f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)(y-x)$$

Specifically, I understand that

$$f'(x) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$$ by definition of a derivative with respect to $t$, but I don't follow how

$$f'(x)(y-x) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x + t(y-x))-f(x)}{t}$$

Comment: **Hint:** Set $h:=t(y-x)$.

Comment: Thank you @Berci for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $h = t(y-x)$ and noting that $h\rightarrow0$ as $t\rightarrow0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)}{t(y-x)} \\\\
f'(x)(y-x)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)}{t}
\end{align}$$